# DNS http -> https Browser cache

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, caching, dns

**Stack:**
MacOs
Chrome:latest
Firefox:latest

**Situation:**
My Website does not provide valid SSL certs.
My server redirects http -> https for the rule Host:example.com.
After changing the rule to allow http only, I ran into this weird issue.

Chrome, the browser I use for testing hast an invalid state.
Firefox which I never use has the right state.

**Expected behaviour:**
On request http://example.com chrome shows the right content + 200.
On request http://example.com firefox (any browser) shows the right content + 200.

**Actual behaviour:**
On request http://example.com chrome redirects to https://example.com.
On request http://example.com firefox(any new browser) shows the right content + 200.

Looks Like a caching issue within chrome, but I do not know which one.
Please point me into a direction.

**Furthermore:**
Anyway ideas how to Setup my Mac dir advanced web dev/sys admin stuff?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In chrome for http to https it uses something called as HSTS (http strict transport security) which forces chrome to connect only over https for the given website.

This has a max-age parameter which is used by the chrome to keep forcing to https version.

Below are the steps to remove your domain from HSTS -

- In the address bar, type “chrome://net-internals/#hsts”.
- Type the domain name in the text field below “Delete domain”.
- Click the “Delete” button.
- Type the domain name in the text field below “Query domain”.
- Click the “Query” button.
- Your response should be “Not found”.

After following these steps, chrome should no longer redirect to https version.

Comment: Thanks @mdeora for the fast answer. I came up earlier with your solution through research on the web. Unfortounately this does not solve the problem. Is there any kind of cache clearing, restart, ... task needed?

Comment: whats the http status code you see in devtools when you type http url?